Fracture Mountain's damage

Immanence The titan’s breaker deals 2 additional spirit damage per weapon damage die to creatures it Strikes. Constructs and objects are not immune to this spirit damage, and this spirit damage automatically bypasses an amount of their Hardness equal to your level.


Transcendence—Fracture Mountains [two-act (spirit, transcendence) Your spirit is so dense it takes on tangible force. Make a melee Strike with the titan’s breaker. This counts as two attacks when calculating your multiple attack penalty. If this Strike hits, your additional spirit damage from the ikon’s immanence increases to 4 plus an extra die of weapon damage. If you’re at least 10th level, it’s increased to 6 spirit damage and two extra dice, and if you’re at least 18th level, it’s increased to 8 spirit damage and three extra dice.

On level 1, is the additional damage simply 4, or 4 per damage die?
This guide says per damage die, but that that seems excessive, on level 19 with Major Striking just the extra spirit damage would be 8 * 4 = 32. Add 3d10 (16,5 on average), and it is way more than what a Magus could do with a Spellstrike using any cantrip.
It is a unlimited resource, if you do not need to move you can do it every round with Shift Immanence.

The wording is unclear
My first take was that the Immanence 'per damage die' equation is what is being adjusted, and that it really is intended to do 32+3dxx damage (48.5 average for your suggested 1d10 weapon) if/when you get a Major Striking Rune. You compare this to a Magus using Spellstrike with a 9-10th Rank Cantrip (which is fair, as a 2-Action Activity that boosts damage and requires a simple Class-based reset), and it is technically more than gouging claw's 35-38.5, but that doesn't account for spells' other effects (such as the bleed from gouging claw).
This number isn't crazy imbalanced, and is actually kind of par for a Class generally seen as the most powerful Martial (from what I've read) numbers-wise.

However, after reading it a half dozen times, the text is

If this Strike hits, your additional spirit damage from the ikon’s immanence increases to 4 plus an extra die of weapon damage.

"To" implies a total replacement of the existing text, not an amalgamation of the constituent parts. If it was definitely the first interpretation put forward by the guide, they could have used much clearer language e.g. "If this Strike hits, your additional spirit damage from the ikon’s immanence increases to 4 'per weapon damage die' plus an extra die of weapon damage." or even "If this Strike hits, your additional spirit damage 'per weapon damage die' from the ikon’s immanence increases to 4 plus an extra die of weapon damage."
However, I would have preferred, if it is the second interpretation, that they use different language as well e.g. "If this Strike hits, your additional spirit damage from the ikon’s immanence is changed to 4 plus an extra die of weapon damage." to make it clear that the increase is intended to be inherent in the improved numbers.
Using the reduced interpretation, that drops the average damage astoundingly, to 24.5 bonus damage as you approach the end of leveling options. Clearly, this is far less than the example Magus' output you suggested; it's even less than if they used the d4 die cantrips like frostbite.

Ultimately, I'm not sure which it is. Having read it over and over, I suspect that the second, lower, damage is actually intended. But the actual words used are just not clear enough to say.

Found a Reddit comment that pretty succinctly explains why the first interpretation might be more reasonable.

My main problem is not that Fracture Mountain is much stronger than other martials' abilities, but rather that it is much stronger than Exemplar's other abilities

@András I compared Fracture Mountain (as +3dx+32, replaces the immanence's +8) and Mirrored Spirit Strike in a damage calculator with d8 and d12 weapons, levels 1 through 20, against the full -4 to +4 enemy level range. I can assure you that in most circumstances Mirrored Spirit Strike does 10% to 30% more damage than Fracture Mountain. Only at levels 18-20 does Fracture Mountain finally catch up. Mirrored Spirit Strike's second attack at -2 is just that good.

@Ruse, do you mean Flowing Spirit Strike? In a vacuum, yes, but Sure Strike is easy to get

@András No, Mirrored Spirit Strike is the transcend of the Gleaming Blade weapon ikon. The comparison with Fracture Mountain is almost 1:1 as both are 2 action abilities that increase MAP twice.

@Ruse In my copy the transcend of Gleaming Blade is Flowing Spirit Strike

4 Plus an Extra Die of Weapon Damage
The exemplar transcendence ability to Fracture Mountains with their titan's breaker weapon ikon increases the damage of the immanence from 2 additional spirit damage per weapon die to 4 plus an extra die of weapon damage. For some examples with a regular warhammer at 1st level:

base warhammer Strike: 1d8 bludgeoning
empowered warhammer (titan's breaker) Strike: 1d8 bludgeoning plus 2 spirit
empowered warhammer (titan's breaker) Fracture Mountains: 1d8 bludgeoning plus 1d8+4 spirit

And at 18th level the damage increases to 8 plus 3 extra dice of weapon damage. With a major striking warhammer at 18th+ level:

base warhammer Strike: 4d8 bludgeoning
empowered warhammer (titan's breaker) Strike: 4d8 bludgeoning plus 8 spirit
empowered warhammer (titan's breaker) Fracture Mountains: 4d8 bludgeoning plus 3d8+8 spirit

Alternatively, interpreting the increase to damage from Fracture Mountains as only replacing the "2" in the immanence damage would do more than just 4 per damage die, as the extra dice are also included in that increase. So by that interpretation the full Fracture Mountains damage would be "4 plus an extra die of weapon damage per weapon die". While this wouldn't go infinite, it would deal a pretty huge amount of damage with that same 18th+ level example:

empowered warhammer (titan's breaker) per-weapon-die Fracture Mountains: 4d8 bludgeoning plus 12d8+32 spirit

